# Why does syslog-ng drop debug messages when logging remote?

Tags: logging, remote, syslog, syslog-ng

In the local log output, I can see debug messages but these won't show up on the remote logging server. It seems to ignore these but it *does* print warning and error level messages just fine.

These are the local (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) syslog-ng.conf entries:

```
# This is the default behavior of sysklogd package
# Logs may come from unix stream, but not from another machine.
#
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};

destination d_net { udp("1.2.3.4"); };
log { source(s_src); destination(d_net); };
```

`s_src` is also used for local logging so it seems to contain the debug messages.

This is the logging server's (Debian 6.0) config:

```
destination df_remote {
        file(
                "/var/log/remotelogs/from_$HOST"
                create_dirs(yes)
                owner(root)
                group(root)
                perm(0644)
                dir_perm(0777)
         );
};

source s_remote { udp(); };

log { source(s_remote); destination(df_remote); };
```

So apparently no log filter of any kind is applied but still debug messages don't get through. What could be the issue here?

Comment: A few things that will help you track the issue down - run a tcpdump on the logging server to see if the messages are coming in - "tcpdump port 514". If you see them coming in, start syslog-ng in debugging mode to see if they are getting filtered out - "syslog-ng -Fdve".

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a protocol designed to deliver its packets timely, at the expense of lossiness.  Whenever there is a problem with packet delivery, the packets will just be dropped. See e.g. [this explanation](http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/SSH-SyslogNG.html).

Comment: My network structure is very straightforward and I haven't had any packet loss issues yet. Even if packet loss was a problem, this would not explain why not a single debug message gets through while other messages do.